# Limit number of decimals output in a calculation in python

Tags: python, decimal, average

OK, so I have written this code to find an average at the end, but I am trying to figure out how to make it a limited number of decimal places when I print it. I want to limit it to four and I used the .4f but that didn't work there. The entire program works, I just don't like how it looks when my answer for that very last line comes out to be a very long average. Any suggestions?

```
#specify months to use

year=[]
months = ["Jan","Feb","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]

#ask for rainfall per month

for i in months:
    year.append(i+"|"+str(input('Enter '+i+' total rainfall in inches: ')))

key_func = lambda s:s.split("|")[1]
split_func = lambda s,index:s.split("|")[index]

#calculate minimums and maximums 

min_rainfall = min(year,key=key_func)
print("The lowest monthly amount of rainfall was "+split_func(min_rainfall,1)+" inches in "+split_func(min_rainfall,0))

max_rainfall = max(year,key=key_func)
print("The highest monthly amount of rainfall was "+split_func(max_rainfall,1)+" inches in "+split_func(max_rainfall,0))

#calculate total and average

total = sum([float(split_func(p,1)) for p in year])
print("Total Rainfall For the Year: "+str(total)+" inches")

print("Average Monthly Rainfall: "+str(float(total/len(year)))+" inches")
```

Comment: You mention the print specifier in your question but you aren't using it, anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
print("Average Monthly Rainfall: {0:.4f} inches".format(total/len(year)))
```

Comment: Or just `{:.4f}`; the `0` is not needed.